# when i was pattern search, i want to search multiful line

Tags: python, regex

i have some question.
Multiple lines at a time and I want to match
Does not multiple lines at once rather than one line search?

These result when i run the code.
Between ^ and $ if you can use other variables.

```
pattern = r'.INFO..+Content'
m = re.compile(pattern,re.S|re.X)

f = open(LOG_FILE)

data = f.read()
print m.search(data).group()
f.close()
```

now output
    [INFO] 0408| 09:50:16.57| /lib/smtp/smtp.c:670| [1120794944] [<<< RECEIVED <<<]
    (16465.2500)     SMTP COMMAND : MAIL FROM: >^M

```
[INFO] 0408| 09:50:16.57| /lib/smtp/smtp.c:670| [1120794944] [>>>   SEND   >>>] 
(16465.2500)     SMTP COMMAND : 250 2.1.5 Ok^M

[INFO] 0408| 09:50:16.58| /lib/smtp/smtp.c:670| [1120794944] [<<< RECEIVED <<<] 
(16465.2500)     SMTP COMMAND : RCPT TO: >^M

[INFO] 0408| 09:50:16.58| /lib/smtp/smtp.c:670| [1120794944] [>>>   SEND   >>>] 
(16465.2500)     SMTP COMMAND : 250 2.1.0 Ok^M

Date: Mon, 08 Apr 2013 09:50:19 +0900^M
Sender: +821057033705/TYPE=PLMN^M
From: +821057033705/TYPE=PLMN^M
To: +821046903908/TYPE=PLMN^M
X-Mms-Message-ID: 1Tf48000001^M
X-Mms-Transaction-ID: 1Tf48000001^M
Content-Type: text/plain;charset="UTF-8"^M
Content
```

Comment: Please show some example input and output.

Comment: Unless your goal is to match either the letter `I`, `N`, `F` or `O` at the start of the regex, you need to escape the brackets (`\[INFO\]`), too.

Comment: I'm finally saw the writing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs (http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) state; `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE`.

There's probably no need to loop through the file-lines anymore either when regex-ing multiline :)

Comment: lig file is very big. maybe 5G. so i need to loop. :)

Comment: I see :). `re.M` should do the trick tho ^^, but the file is probably already getting split on `\n`-linebreaks right? You might want to do something like `^`-`$` to match the beginning of the string until the end. Of course there might something unique about your file :)

Comment: `re.MULTILINE` is somewhat confusing name, because it has nothing to do with matching multiple lines at once. It only tell how special characters `^` and `$` should be interpreted.

Comment: Then just use dotall to let `.` match newline characters too?